# Should zergoverflow.com not be merged with gaming?

Tags: discussion

ZO seems to be very focused subset of gaming. Is there a particular reason it is not merged with gaming?

Comment: The same question applies to EpicAdvice.com, a WoW-focused Q&A site. I also feel this should be up to the administrators of those sites. They've put a lot of time and money into their sites, since before the current Stack Exchange launch model was developed.

Comment: @Wik, in other news I think I recall their money was going to be refunded.

Answer (score 1):

This is up to the administrators of ZergOverflow to decide.

Actually -- given the content license, we *could* programmatically "import" data from it, but we'd have to give [proper attribution.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/) (The reverse also applies, obviously.) If you feel this is a good enough idea to implement, [ask for it on **Meta StackOverflow**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?title=Please+implement+automatic+migration+of+questions+and+answers+from+StackExchange+1.0+sites+with+CC-By-SA+licenses&tags=feature-request+stackexchange-1.0+stackexchange-2.0+migration), where all engine questions belong.