# ZergOverflow seems down

Tags: support, migration

Is the site gone down for good? How was their content licensed?

Comment: Overflom? Is it actually overflom? I know it's probably a typo, but an M is like an upside down W much like a Z is a backwards S, so maybe it's a nonce joke. Or summat.

Comment: I came to edit it and then I saw your comment @Grace

Comment: @Grace nope, just an old fashioned typo.

Answer (score 1):

According to Whois, their domain name expired on November 28th (1 year after its creation). Probably either someone forgot to pay the registrar for the next year, or they chose not to renew it. I can't really say which.

For more info on their licensing, see this question:
[Should zergoverflow.com not be merged with gaming?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1254/should-zergoverflow-com-not-be-merged-with-gaming)